# Is there a way to replace missing values based on percentage?

Tags: r

For example, if I have a variable that takes 2 values `Left` and `Right`. And the counts are as follows:

```
Left Right 
973   897
```

And say I have 500 missing values. The % of missing values replaced with `Left` will be `973/(973+897)` and the % of missing values replaced with `Right` will be `897/(973+897)`.

How to do this? Or is this a bad idea?

Comment: If `left` and `right` are independent variables, maybe interpolating would help?

Comment: Can you show more of your data?

Comment: Yes they are. Can you show how could it be done by code?

Comment: @amnesic Can you provide us a part of your dataframe?

Answer (score 1):

If your dataset is something like this -

```
vec <- sample(rep(c('Left', 'Right', NA), c(10, 15, 10)))
```

You can perform the proportion calculation and replace `NA` values by -

```
prop <- prop.table(table(vec)) * sum(is.na(vec))
vec[is.na(vec)] <- sample(rep(names(prop), prop))
vec
```

Comment: Is there any benefit to do this than replacing with mode of a column?

Answer (score 0):

If interpolating can help, this  is how, in principle, it works:

Test data:

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(
   left = c(rnorm(5), NA, NA, rnorm(5), NA, rnorm(5))
)
```

Solution: To replace the `NA`values with linearly interpolated values use `zoo`'s function `na.approx`:

```
library(zoo)
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   mutate(left_intpl = na.approx(left))
          left  left_intpl
1  -0.56047565 -0.56047565
2  -0.23017749 -0.23017749
3   1.55870831  1.55870831
4   0.07050839  0.07050839
5   0.12928774  0.12928774
6           NA  0.65788015
7           NA  1.18647257
8   1.71506499  1.71506499
9   0.46091621  0.46091621
10 -1.26506123 -1.26506123
11 -0.68685285 -0.68685285
12 -0.44566197 -0.44566197
13          NA  0.38920991
14  1.22408180  1.22408180
15  0.35981383  0.35981383
16  0.40077145  0.40077145
17  0.11068272  0.11068272
18 -0.55584113 -0.55584113
```

Comment: Is there any benefit to do this than replacing with mode of a column?

Comment: I'm not a mthematician but I do think there is. The mode is just the most frequent value in a distribution. A linear interpolation looks at the neighbouring values and estimates what are the most likely values given these neighbouring values in case of NA.

Comment: Consider a distribution like this: `x <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1, 555, 1000, NA, 2555)`. The `NA`value is clearly unlikely to be `1`, which is the mode but much more likely to be in-between the two neighbouring values, as in `na.approx(x)
 [1]    1.0    1.0    1.0    1.0    1.0    1.0    1.0    1.0  555.0 1000.0 1777.5 2555.0`

Comment: But it really depends on the nature of your data. If order matters, then interpolation is useful. If it doesn't then perhaps use the mode.

Comment: Order doesn't matter so interpolation is not helpful. But in my case of `Left` and `Right` and the count for both of them is almost equal, if I replace with mode, doesn't that seem just wrong?

Comment: If left and right are **strongly** related then replace the missing value on the one side with the present value on the other side.

Comment: They are not related either as far as I can tell. This is for patient data. So each patient has either left or right.

Comment: If they're unrelated why is the count for both of them "almost equal", as you say? Or do you mean the total count of cases?

Comment: I guess I've gotten confused on what you mean by related. The variable itself may be related to other variables in the dataset. What I mean to say is there's equal chances of the value itself being left or right. 897 vs 973 from available data. So the missing data could be either. If I replace with just the higher value, I'm worried it would affect my model. And order doesn't matter.